# Will Delphi be available as both EM64 and IA64?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

I have seen many 64-bit applications come in two 64-bit versions. One is x86-64 and other is IA64. Will Delphi's 64-bit version also have this?

Comment: and what the server developers can do in future

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Delphi 64 bit **will** target x86-64, a.k.a. AMD64, a.k.a. EM64T.

It **will not** target the Itanium architecture IA64.

I consider the possibility of Delphi ever supporting Itanium to be vanishingly small since the Itanium platform has been deprecated.

Comment: Proof link please, or you are a Delphi team insider ;)

Comment: @Serg Since this is an unreleased product, I'm not sure there is an official document stating this.  The [road map](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934), for example, is not specific. Allen Bauer's twitter stream, and his podcast interview by Jim McKeeth make it clear that there are working only on x86-64.

Comment: @Serg, on the [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium#Timeline) page at Wikipedia, you get this [link about Microsoft ending support for Itanium in April 2010](http://www.pcworld.com/article/193426/microsoft_ending_support_for_itanium.html) and then the real killer [Intel drops support for Itanium in it's compilers](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-composer-xe-2011-release-notes/), January 2011.

Comment: @Serg Anyway, I know you are toying with me because you know that my statement is correct!!

Comment: Yes good move by intel and embarcadero , no need to invest on nonprofit projects

Comment: @David: I know that your statement should be true, but you can never be sure what the next Delphi release will be ;)

Comment: Nobody who has even 0.01% of a brain would write a brand new IA64 instruction set targeting compiler at this point in time.  Anyone remember when Windows NT supported PowerPC and MIPS? :-)

Comment: Although it would be silly to support IA64 in Delphi, Intel has just announced its next Itanium processor, Poulson. Not yet an abandoned platform by Intel/HP.

Comment: Warren P: Windows will support ARM instead now.

Comment: @David, You're rockin' the rep now!

Comment: @Allen Ha! Yeah, looks like my pre-emptive strike did the trick!! You get rep for the strangest things though. This was a total whiffle ball! And now it's over to you to deliver product.... :-)

Answer (score 19):

David is right. x86-64, AMD64, EM64T will be the 64bit CPU supported initially. Windows 64bit will be the initial OS supported.

Comment: Ah shucks, now you'll get all the up-votes and the accept 'cos of who you are!!  ;-)

Comment: @David: You just need to add a flashy image to your answer. :) At any rate, I think it is really great that Embarcadero is present here at SO.

Comment: @Andreas No I agree that it's great that Allen, Barry and even old-boy Danny contribute here on SO. I hope my winky made it clear I was joking!

Comment: @David, You deserve the accept for answering first and correctly. I merely confirmed. I find your answers to be on the mark the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @Allen Thanks. Anyway, your answer carries the weight of authority, so that probably ought to count for something!

Comment: Any hint when the compiler will be available?

Comment: @Andrei K. - Of course not. As an Embarcadero employee, that would be making a product announcement, and SO would be a strange place for that to be done. (And Allen probably likes keeping his job. <g>)

Comment: Actually I think SO would be an ideal place for one product announcement. Just for laughs, especially if they did it as an aside to another answer. "normally .... but in the new version of Delphi we released today ..."

Comment: @moz, Allen's bosses would probably prefer it be done somewhere more "official", say for instance the Embarcadero website, I'd think. :) And they'd probably prefer it not be a "hint" or a "guess" or an "estimate" that they might not want to be committed to yet.